# NetValidatePasswordPolicy issue on XP

Tags: visual-c++, windows-xp, reflector, netapi32

My project has a requirement that it needs to check the password complexity before create the new account.

```
My code looks like:

NET_API_STATUS status;
NET_VALIDATE_PASSWORD_CHANGE_INPUT_ARG inputArg = {0};
NET_VALIDATE_OUTPUT_ARG* pOutputArg = NULL;

inputArg.ClearPassword = NewPass;    
inputArg.PasswordMatch = TRUE;

status = NetValidatePasswordPolicy(DC, NULL, NetValidatePasswordChange,
            &inputArg, (void**)&pOutputArg);    
printf("status: %d, validationStatus: %d\n", status, pOutputArg->ValidationStatus);

NetValidatePasswordPolicyFree((void**)&pOutputArg);
```

I am working on windows XP.When I try to run, it prompt waring saying:

**The procedure entry point NetValidPasswordPolicyFree could not be located in the dynamic link library NETAPI32.dll**

From the MSDN it said the API is only valid in 2003 server and 2008 server. 
    Does it mean it can not work on XP?
    Or can i find any other APIs to do the same thing as NetValidPasswordPolicy?

I googled a lot for this issue and found someone had asked similar question but it went unanswered :(. So, here I am trying my luck.

Even I tried to analyze `'NETAPI32.dll'` in Reflector.exe, but while opening the .dll file it error out: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I am stuck badly and could not able to find any way. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved :).

`NetValidPasswordPolicy` API from `'NETAPI32.dll'` has requirements that it is not 'client' supported. Because of this requirement I am getting the warning: `Entry point not found.`
I tried my project on Windows 2003 server and it worked.

And my second question about 'Reflector.exe' is also invalid because `'NETAPI32.dll'` is not .Net dll so Reflector wont recognize it.